# Linux core dump for current stack only

Tags: linux, coredump

I want to resolve an application crash running on linux-3.10.85 for which I am generating the core dump. Due to space constraints, I just want the current process stack to be present in the core dump (the memory which is referred to as RSS in linux). I have found something useful for Solaris OS but unable to find anything relevant for Linux. Is this possible in linux? If yes, is there any other way to analyse the core dump file apart from gdb?

[Link](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19253-01/816-5166/coreadm-1m/index.html) to coreadm utility for Solaris which solves this problem.

I have already tried setting the `coredump_filter` in the `/proc` file system but it does not seem to be working.

Comment: Related https://stackoverflow.com/q/8836459/72178

Comment: RSS is not the current stack. It's the parts of virtual memory that happen to be loaded into physical RAM.